# $.mobile.changePage not working in IE9 but works in FireFox(12)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9

am using IE9.

The following code works fine in FireFox 12

```
    var sst;
    sst = '<li>test12</li>';
    $.mobile.changePage('#ChooseProg', { transition: "slideup" });                                        
    $('#RepData').html(sst);
```

This is what the ChoosProg page looks like:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="ChooseProg" data-title="Choose Prog">

     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-btn-right" style="min-height:42px;">
     <h1>Select Program</h1>            
     </div>

     <div data-role="content">          
     <ul id="RepData" data-role="listview" data-filter="false" data-inset="true">   
     <li>
     </ul>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>          
     </div><!-- /content -->

     <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-btn-right" style="min-height:42px;">
     </div>

     </div> <!-- /page -->
```

In IE9, it gives no errors and I doesn't seem to go to the ChooseProg page.

Comment: Can you post more complete code? Seems like there may just be a syntax issue or something.

Comment: I've been having this problem as well. It may be a bug in JQM, someone reported it on github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4027